# Problemas al indexar los elementos de una lista

Tags: python, lambda, indices

Quiero tener una lista de las `temps` cambiadas usando `lambda`, ¿qué problema tiene mi código?

```
f1=lambda c:c+273.15
print(f1(8),"K") 
temps = [12, 23, 38, -55, 24]
print(list(f1(temps[c])),"K")
```

Answer (score 0):

El error en si es un `NameError` porque `c` no está definida:

```
print(list(f1(temps[c])),"K")
                    ^
                    ^
```

`f1(temps[c])` no itera sobre la lista y aplica la función a cada item como creo que esperas, simplemente trata de indizar sobre `temp` con el valor de `c` (que nada tiene que ver con el argumento de `f1`) y el resultado pasarlo a `f1` como argumento.

Si quieres aplicar la función a cada item de la lista debes usar `map`:

> ```
> >>> list(map(f1,  temps))
> [285.15, 296.15, 311.15, 218.14999999999998, 297.15]
> ```

O alternativamente iterar con un `for` en una lista por compresión:

> ```
> >>> [f1(item) for item in temps]
> [285.15, 296.15, 311.15, 218.14999999999998, 297.15]
> ```

Ten en cuenta que asignar un nombre a una expresión `lambda` tiene poco sentido, para eso defines una función normal:

```
def celsius_to_kelvin(temp):
    return temp + 273.15
```

> ```
> >>> list(map(celsius_to_kelvin,  temps))
> ```

La idea de una expresión lambda es poder hacer cosas como:

> ```
> >>> list(map(lambda c: c + 273.15,  temps))
> ```